# Guardar datos de un while en un array php

Tags: php

es que quiero guardar los datos de un `while` en un `array`, como lo tengo escrito solo me guarda un dato en el arreglo cuando lo imprimo, pero cuando pongo el `var_dump` dentro de ciclo `while` si guarda todo.

```
<table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Cod Materia</th>
                    <th>Notas</th>
                    <th>Periodo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $i = 1;

                while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
                    if (oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL') > 3 ){
                        $notas = [oci_result($stid, 'MATE_CODIGOMATERIA')];
                       
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'MATE_CODIGOMATERIA'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo oci_result($stid, 'PEUN_ID'); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                  
                }

                var_dump($notas);

                oci_free_statement($stid);
                oci_close($conn);

                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Es justamente en:

```
while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
                        if (oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL') > 3 ){
                            $notas = [oci_result($stid, 'MATE_CODIGOMATERIA')];
                           
                        }
```

Creo que no lo estoy guardando correctamente y estos datos provienen de una `BD Oracle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis correcta para agregar valores a un arreglo es la siguiente:

```
$array = []; // Creación del arreglo
$array[] = $valor; // Agregamos valores al arreglo
```

Aplicado a tu código sería:

```
/// ... código anterior
$i = 1;
$notas = []; // Definimos la variable como un arreglo

while (oci_fetch($stid)) {

    if (oci_result($stid, 'REAC_NOTAFINAL') > 3 ){

        // Agregamos valores al arreglo
        $notas[] = oci_result($stid, 'MATE_CODIGOMATERIA');
    }
/// ... resto del código
```